# Difference between Cluster and JVM

Tags: java, static, jvm, distributed-computing

What is the difference between a cluster and JVM?

How does a static variable behave in clustered environment? Does it belong to a cluster or to the individual JVMs?

Comment: what apples and oranges?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it does not provide any searchable value, specifically it asks for a comparison between very different objects that have nothing to do with each other.

Answer (score 1):

Broadly speaking, a cluster is a group of computing nodes configured to work together.

It sounds like you are talking in the context of a J2EE server, so in that case, a cluster will consist of several application servers and each application server will run within its own JVM.

Static variables will be local to the JVM, and so not shared across the cluster.

In fact, data won't be shared across a cluster except in specific circumstances, e.g.: you have session replication configured, or some sort of RPC going on.